# Laravel Where and OrWhere

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to figure out how to create the following query in eloquent:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `pvp_battles` 
WHERE (player1_id = 2 || player2_id =2) && winner !=2
```

2 is the player id. This is what I did:

```
$profile->loses = PvpBattle::where('player1_id',$profile->id)
        ->orWhere('player2_id',$profile->id)
        ->where('winner','!=',$profile->id)->count();
```

Sadly it shows that the count is 49 while it's 25.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the fix:

```
$profile->loses = PvpBattle::where(function($q) use($profile) {
  return $q
           ->where('player1_id', $profile->id)
           ->orWhere('player2_id', $profile->id);
})->where('winner', '!=', $profile->id)->count();
```

or:

```
$profile->loses = PvpBattle::where(DB::raw($profile->id.' IN (`player1_id`, `player2_id`)'))
                           ->where('winner', '!=', $profile->id)->count();
```

Answer (score 2):

how about?

```
$profile->loses = PvpBattle::where(function($query) use ($profile){
    $query->where('player2_id', '=', $profile->id)
    ->orWhere('player1_id', '=', $profile->id);
})
->where('winner','!=',$profile->id)->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You were wrong in evaluating OR and AND conditions. If the values are one by one the logical is that first evaluates AND and the OR. Your algorithm must be (Test1 OR Test 2) AND Test 3.
If they are alltogether
Test1 OR Test 2 AND Test 3 the logic first tests Test2 AND Test3 then makes an OR with Test 1.

The right codes needs a "closure function":

```
$profile->loses = PvpBattle::where(function($q) use($profile) {  return $q
       ->where('player1_id', $profile->id)
       ->orWhere('player2_id', $profile->id); }) ->where('winner', '!=', $profile->id)->count();
```